# __init __.py not taking effecting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started to program an rpg game in python 3. Here is the error I get when running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from characters.player  import *
  File "/home/darcey/python/characters/player.py", line 2, in <module>
    from character import *
ImportError: No module named 'character'
```

Here is my file structure:

```
| = folder
~ = file

| python
    | characters
        ~ __init__.py
        ~ player.py
        ~ character.py
        ~ enemy.py
    ~ main.py
```

If I need to put all the code in or code from certain files just comment below and I'll add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a *package relative import*:

```
from .character import *
```

Note the `.`; you don't have a global `character` module, only a local one.

Alternatively, use an absolute import:

```
from characters.character import *
```